# Android Geocoder fails processing german umlauts UTF8-encoded

Tags: android, utf-8

I try to use the Android Geocoder to encode a user entered postal address to a coordinate. Despite on UTF-8 encoding, everytime I use umlauts like ü, ö, ß, the geocoder gets no results. If I replace the letters with ue, oe or ss, then it works fine.

```
String text = "Schöneberger Straße, Berlin, Germany";
text = URLEncoder.encode(text, "UTF-8");
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(applicationContext, Locale.GERMANY);
List<Address> fromLocationName = geocoder.getFromLocationName(text, 1);
```

fromLocationName appears to be empty.

I am using Android 2.3

Comment: try with ISO-8859-1 istead of utf8

Comment: SCNR, but ß is no umlaut.

Comment: No, ISO-8859-1 does not work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that Geocoder does not need any encoding. Passing the raw strings to it did it finally. Strange, I thought this would not work, but now it does. 
Thanks.